# Property $(V_1)$ for Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This aim of this note is to record a problem that still seems to be open.

Räbiger, in his doctoral thesis, defined property $(V_1)$ as follows: A Banach space $X$ has property $(V_1)$ if every unconditionally converging operator $T:X\to c_0$ is weakly compact.

It is worth to remember that a Banach space $X$ has property $(V)$ if and only if every unconditionally converging operator $T:X\to\ell^{\infty}$ is weakly compact.

Is there a Banach space that has property $(V_1)$ but not property $(V)$?

.

PS: A necessary and sufficient condition is that the unit ball of $X^{\ast}$ contains an $\ell^1$ sequence $(f_n)$ satisfying

- $(f_n)$ has no weak* convergent subsequence.
- $f_n(x_n)\to 0$ for any wuC series $\sum x_n$ in $X$.